Error while parcel watch: You gave us a visitor for the node type StaticBlock but it's not a valid type
When i am trying to run: "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js" i get this error. I've tried answers of this question but it didnt work.
index.js:
import '@babel/polyfill';
import { displayMap } from './mapbox';
import { login } from './login';

// DOM ELEMENTS
const mapbox = document.getElementById('map');
const loginForm = document.querySelector('.form');

// DELEGATION
if (mapbox) {
  const locations = JSON.parse(mapbox.dataset.locations);
  displayMap(locations);
}

if (loginForm) {
  document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    login(email, password);
  });
}


login.js:
import axios from 'axios';

export const login = async (email, password) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: {
        email,
        password,
      },
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      alert('Logged in successfully!');
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.assign('/');
      }, 1500);
    }

    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.response.data.message);
  }
};


I've tried to delete node_modules but nothing changed
